# Update manager fails to calculate upgrade

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

Recently, when running the update manager, and after checking package info. shows this message.

```
Could not calculate the upgrade

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:'E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.'
```

Comment: what message do you if you type "sudo apt-get update" followed by "sudo apt-get upgrade" in a terminal Ahmed?

Comment: Are you upgrading 10.04 → 10.10, or something else? Can you also tar/zip the folder `/var/log/dist-upgrade` and upload it somewhere so that we can have a look at it?

Comment: no error appear after typing "sudo apt-get update", but after "sudo apt-get upgrade" asked me to download 684MB updates. -allan

Comment: no i'm not upgrading for 10.10, so the folder dist-upgrade is empty! -arrange

Comment: OK, so can you post or upload somewhere the output of `sudo apt-get upgrade`? (You can say cancel the upgrade then when asked for confirmation.)

Comment: Offtopic: This is the third issue I came across with the update manager in the last two days. I faced this error - http://img6.imagebanana.com/img/hxtshc9i/Untitledwindow_030.png and I fixed it by removing the package list (I guess, I am not sure) and then regenerating them by sudo apt-get upgrade. Well now my comment doesn't make any sense here at all. :P

Answer (score 2):

Download the updates and see what happens. `sudo apt-get upgrade`