# Upgrading to 12.04 from 11.10; cannot calculate the upgrade?

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, upgrade, update-manager

So I'm trying to upgrade from Onereic to Pangolin using the Update Manager.  Fine.  Except that I get this error in the `"Setting new software channels"` phase;

```
Could not calculate the upgrade

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade:
E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.



This can be caused by:
 * Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu
 * Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu
 * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command 'ubuntu-bug update-manager' in a terminal.
```

I do have a lot of PPAs, but I've disabled all of them.  Someone told me to use ppa-purge on all of them, but I don't think I'm doing it correctly.  Remember, I've successfully upgraded to 11.10 FROM 11.04 with all of these PPAs activated.  Any tips?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/27968/update-manager-fails-to-calculate-upgrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your terminal and run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get do-release-upgrade
```

Then try again.