# Cannot upgrade from Kubuntu 13.10 to 14.04

Tags: updates

The upgrade tool start. When finished "Setting new software channels" give me an error: "Could not calculate the upgrade". Any ideas? Thx

Comment: Can you run `do-release-upgrade` from the terminal and see if it gives more information there about the error?

Comment: Thx flor your answer. I did it yesterday with same result.

Comment: See if this question helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/449546/ubuntu-13-10-to-14-04-lts-does-not-upgrade-keeps-showing-error#comment590353_449546

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update manager fails to calculate upgrade](http://askubuntu.com/questions/27968/update-manager-fails-to-calculate-upgrade)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only good way to solve this issue is to check the error at the bottom of either "/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log" or "/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log" and see which package is causing you trouble. In my case, it was xserver-xorg-video-all. I removed it and the upgrade continued just fine.

Comment: Have the same problem. How do you remove those packages?

Comment: Just do an "sudo apt-get remove <packagename>" from the command line. Alternatively, if the package is part of a PPA you added, you can look up how to use ppa-purge to remove the PPA from your system.

Comment: I had the same problem. It was caused by a dodgy version of postgresql that was on the "blacklist" - couldn't be removed or upgraded. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.